# 'nest build' fails with 'FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory'

Tags: typescript, nestjs

My nest project runs fine under the VS Code debugger but it fails to build from the command line, with a message:

> FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

- nest 9.0.0
- node 16.16.0

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround as follows: created new project, copied all source files to the new project, now all works.
I suspect the TS compiler had cached data about my old folder... as the projects are otherwise identical.